# Docusign consent issue with 2nd user, is duplicate of 1st working

Tags: docusignapi

Running into a bit of an odd issue. I assume it may be a setting somewhere?

Using the API integration for embedded forms. We have two brands, so I've made two users with the same roles. Their job is to be the sender for any embedded form for their respective brand. Their roles are both set as `sender` from the user settings tab.

1. support@brand.com
2. support@other-brand.com

Each user is in 2 groups, developers and their respective brand. Simply being part of developers will allow them to be assigned as the sender of any API templates. It's worth noting, these two users are identical to one another in setup, only difference being support email.

Using user 1, there are no issues, and everything works as intended. Using user 2 however, I get the error "consent required" when trying to get a JWT token?

I've gone through all and any settings I could find, but nothing seems to do what I need. Both users belong to the organization, so I'm simple confused.

Any help and direction is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The answer was I needed to claim the @brand URL the 2nd user was under, which had not been claimed via the application admin interface.

Answer (score 0):

Consent is per user, you would need the second user to log in and navigate to the URL For consent.
If you are using the developer/sandbox/demo environment (not production) the URL you would want to set looks like this:

```
https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=signature%20impersonation&client_id=<your IK>&redirect_uri=<some URL you defined for the IK>
```

Remember to define the redirect_uri in the Apps and Keys page in the settings page where you created the Integraiton Key and you should be good.

Comment: Even with the API integration? I can say for certain, I did not do this with the 1st user.

Comment: I can say with certain this was done for the 1st user, maybe you didn't but consent is a requirement to use the API, so it has to have been done.

Comment: I created both users yesterday, so I'm fairly certain the consent screen was not a part of the process.

Without getting into a back and forth, is there any other way this could be done? I will try the link you sent also, thank you.

Comment: So I can confirm, using the link you posted is not necessary for an API integration. I deleted the user, a re-signed up with the exact same credentials. Just works now. No asks for consent or the like. Thank you for your comments and help none the less.

Comment: aha, you used administrative consent and the other user was in a different URL. Sorry, different way to do things...